# How can I see which Pages a User requests in Grails?

Tags: spring, grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I use the Grails [Application Info Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/app-info) to get active sessions as:

```
ScopesInfoService scopesInfoService

List<Map<String, Object>> activeSessionsMap = scopesInfoService.getSessionsInfo()
activeSessionsMap.each { sessionMap ->
            def tmpSession = sessionMap.session
}
```

How can I see which page a user with a session has been requested and is requesting?

Comment: Not sure why you need the plugin for this.  request.forwardURI

Comment: @Gregg I want to see which URI each session is requestion? How can I do that?

Comment: sessions don't request URI's. requests do.  request.forwardURI will tell you what URI is being requested.

Comment: @Gregg I know but how can see which pages a user is accessing when i only have there Sessions?

Comment: See @Alidad's answer.  That is what I was going to suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a filter and store the current `controller` and `action` or `request.forwardURI` for each request in a variable called currentLocation or something. When you access sessions just read that. you can be creative with it and store any data. but not sure this is a proper approach anyway.

```
storeLocation(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                session.currentLocation = "$controllerName/$actionName"
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is bad with your approach?

Comment: Generally putting data in session might not be a good idea, but for this purpose it is fine.

Comment: Why is it bad to store data in session? does it slow down the app?

Comment: Where should I put the filter in? I do not want it to be in every controller.

Comment: Grails filter will be in configuration folder. If you just google it it will be the first link. http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html

Comment: over using session with un-managed data is not good. Must be used with caution.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin will not give you that. You need to develop something yourself. 
You can create a [grails Filter](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) that saves to your database (create a new table for this) the information about the session, user and about the URI (your pages) is being requested.

Sample filter:

```
class UserInfoFilters {
    def filters = {
            all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
                before = {
                    SessionUserInfoDomainClass s = new SessionUserInfoDomainClass()
                    // populate your domain class above with the info you need. Examples:
                    s.user = session.user
                    s.controller = controllerName
                    s.save()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Then you can easily have some UI (even with [scaffolg](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/single.html#scaffolding)) of this SessionUserInfoDomainClass to read the info you want.

Comment: Where should I put the filter in? I do not want it to be in every controller.

Comment: I have put the Filters docs link in my answer. You will find more info in the docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters (the place to put the filters is in grails-app/conf/ folder)